# Save Webpage complete into a single file, including linked mp3 file

Tags: google-chrome, browser, mp3, webpage

## I want to

- Save a webpage, complete (including linked CSS, JavaScript, images etc, **including a linked mp3 (or any other audio) file.**
- Having only one single file of type "mhtml", which is a multipart file.
- Later be able to open this single file with (any) browser and see the page as it was when downloaded (including the audio file)

This is the URL I want to save:

https://quirli.replayer.app/player.html?media=media%2Flidija_roos-sweet_taste.mp3&title=Sweet%20taste&artist=Lidija%20Roos&album=Not%20for%20sale&0=Intro&15=Verse%201&45.5=Verse%202&75.94=Chorus&106.75=Verse%203&140.75=Chorus&172.07=Bridge&201.65=Chorus&232.65=Outro

Which is an example page from the https://quirli.replayer.app player.

I have been using Google Chrome on both Windows and Ubuntu Linux. It mostly works, but the saved webpage never included the mp3 file. The mp3 file is also missing, when I only try to download the page as usual, generating multiple files.

## What I have done

- configured the Chrome setting for the built-in Webpage-Complete downloads as described here: https://www.tagspaces.org/blog/mhtml-saving-chrome/
- Used the extension "Save As MHTML" https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-as-mhtml/eomfifclcdpkaghkehajpolkdnkmegfa

## What I got

The resulting mhtml so far contains images, CSS, etc, but not the mp3 file. Excerpt from the mthml file:

```
From: <Saved by Blink>
Subject: quirli - replay and share media with cues.
Date: Sun, 14 May 2016 21:39:17 -0000
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related;
    type="text/html";
    boundary="----MultipartBoundary--s0EoeTgs0wh4NBKS7yadKZ1notfzker0FY7TZfz4Ct----"

------MultipartBoundary--s0EoeTgs0wh4NBKS7yadKZ1notfzker0FY7TZfz4Ct----
Content-Type: text/html
Content-ID: <frame-5-FAAFA4DD-411B-4FDD-9511-4EC1CE937A04@mhtml.blink>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Location: https://quirli.replayer.app/player.html?media=media%2Flidija_roos-sweet_taste.mp3&title=Sweet%20taste&artist=Lidija%20Roos&album=Not%20for%20sale&0=Intro&15=Verse%201&45.5=Verse%202&75.94=Chorus&106.75=Verse%203&140.75=Chorus&172.07=Bridge&201.65=Chorus&232.65=Outro

<!DOCTYPE html>
....
```

However, it does not include the mp3 file.

## How to include linked mp3 files in Single-File Webpage-Complete MHTML downloads?

Although I used Chrome so far, any of the major browser would do for me, as long as I can view the resulting page at least in Google Chrome.

Comment: It saves just the links, not the linked files themselves, this is by design for mhtml files.

Comment: @Moab Thanks for your comment, but this is not true. When I examine the gotten mhtml file, images and CSS etc.. are included. Also when disconnected from the internet, I can open the mhtml file and see the full webpage (but except the mp3 file).

Comment: @Marcel The mp3 file is only sent to the browser when you press play on the embedded player.

Comment: @DavidPostill, ok you are right, for the given example. BUT, it also does not work when the mp3 file is just a clickable link, like an linked image. See this page: http://www.christoffankhauser.ch/werkstatt/sing-sag-sugg/ it does have linked mp3 files but I also do not manage to get an mhtml file with the sound included. However, images are included.

Comment: @Marcel Same problem. You have to click on the playback icon to download the mp3. If your look at the Net tab in developer tools in Firefox you will see the mp3 is not automatically downloaded when the page is loaded.